# Как передать данные из Activity в Fragment ViewPager?

Tags: java, android

Вот мой адаптер:

```
public class ScheduleViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int numbers;
private boolean flag;

public ScheduleViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numbers, boolean flag) {
    super(fm);
    this.numbers = numbers;
    this.flag = flag;;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (flag)
        return ScheduleFragment.newInstance(new DateUtils(position).getResultDate());
    else
        return EditScheduleFragment.newInstance(new DateUtils(position).getResultDate());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numbers;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, в чем проблема. Судя по коду, вы их и так передаете в `newInstance(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете доставать данные из вашей активити в которой храните фрагмет.

```
String data = ((YourActivity)getActivity)).getYourData
```